# How to format decimal number to display the preciding zero but not the trailing ones?

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable, arithmetic

I have the following script on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 64-bit bash command prompt:

```
S=0.030
F=0.150
N=10
reso=20
DIFF=`echo "scale=3; $F - $S" | bc -l`
df=`echo "scale=3; $DIFF / $N" | bc -l`
is=`echo "scale=3; $S / $df" | bc -l`
if=`echo "scale=3; $F / $df" | bc -l`
cd wgdisp-out
for i in `seq 0 $N` 
    do
        f=`echo "scale=3; $S + $i * $df" | bc -l | awk ' sub("\\.*0+$","") '`
        #h5totxt hsli0$f.h5 | harminv -vt 0.1 -w 2-3 -a 0.9 -f 200 | sed -n '/^[[:digit:]]/p' | cut -d , -f 1
        echo $f
    done
```

I would like to have f displayed as `0.03, 0.042, 0.054, .... 0.138, 0.15` and this is critical since f is used inside file names such as `hsli0.03.h5`. Can someone point me in the right direction? I am not pretty familiar with arithmetic in shell.

**EDIT**: I tried the following construct, but it does not yield the desired output; furthermore the scale option for `bc` does not seem to work.

```
f=`echo "scale=3; $S + $i * $df" | bc | sed -e 's/^\./0./' -e 's/$^\/0/./'`
```

**EDIT2**: Got it working with the following single command:

```
f=`echo "scale=3; $S + $i * $df" | bc | sed -e 's/^\./0./;s/[0]*$//g'`
```

Comment: Use `awk` instead of `bc`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Unfortunately, I am not that experienced with `regular expression` and `awk` I think I will try the printf solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating point arithmetic support in bash is very poor. You can still use `printf`, though:

```
printf '%5.3f\n' $f
printf '%.3g\n' $f
```

If you just want to prepend 0 to ., you can use parameter expansion:

```
f=${f/#./0.}
# if negative numbers are possible, too
f=${f/#-./-0.}
```

Comment: Well I somehow managed to have the leading zero printed but now I would like to get rid of the trailing zeros is it possible with this construct?

Comment: @Vesnog: Do you really need it? I'd like the fixed-length filenames more.

Comment: I really need it since generating those files took around 3 hours and I do not have that much time right now. So for now I should go with it in `Matlab` there was the format specifier `%g` which takes care of the trailing zeros, do we have it in this `printf` implementation too?

Comment: @Vesnog: Check the update.

Comment: @choraba Okay thanks, I think I should get my hands on regexs ASAP.

Comment: %.3g gives "100" for "100.1" and "1e+03" for 1000 though.

Comment: @Vesnog: There's no regex. It just replaces `.` at the beginning with `0.`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Can I use `sed` to achieve that effect? Like f=`echo "scale=3; $S + $i * $df" | bc | sed -e 's/^\./0./;s/$^\/0/./'`

Comment: @Vesnog: Parameter substitution would be faster than sed. Also, the second substitution makes no sense (there can't be anything after the end of line).

Comment: @choroba As I have said I am not familiar with regexs how can I have `sed` check if there is a trailing zero to remove it.

Answer (score 3):

In `bc`, `scale` is a special variable that is used to limit the *scale* (the number of digits after the comma) of the result of some operators like `/` (division). It is not the precision in numbers displayed by `bc`, it's used in computation.

For instance, in `scale=1; 1/3`, the result is `0.3` (`3/10`), which is quite far from `1/3`.

You should use large scale values for your computation, and only reduce `scale` for display (by instance, by dividing by `1` in the end).

Compare:

```
$ echo "scale=100; r=1/3*300; scale=3; r/1" | bc
99.999
```

with:

```
$ echo "scale=3; 1/3*300" | bc
99.900
```

I'd write it:

```
n=10
echo "
  s = 0.030
  f = 0.150
  n = $n
  r = 20
  scale = 100
  d = (f - s) / n
  scale = 3
  for (i = s; i <= f; i += d) i/1" |
    bc |
    sed 's/^\./0./;s/0*$//' |
    while read f; do
      h5totxt "hsli$f.h5" | harminv -vt 0.1 -w 2-3 -a 0.9 -f 200
    done
```